# On / off sound (IOS)

Tags: ios, audio, swift3, xcode8, calculator

I use this code for buttons for press sounds when pressed.

Is it possible to do so that when you turn off "Switch" - (which is on the second VC), the sound of the buttons on the first VC is turned off?

[image: [VC1 and VC2]

```
 @IBAction func SoundButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let filename = "button-16"
    let ext = "mp3"

    if let soundUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: ext) {
        var soundId: SystemSoundID = 0

        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundUrl as CFURL, &soundId)

        AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundId, nil, nil, { (soundId, clientData) -> Void in
            AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundId)
        }, nil)

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the sound value in a boolean and save it in `UserDefaults` once the switch has changed. You should retrieve this boolean value and set the switch's state accordingly in `cellForRowAt`.

**GlobalVariables.swift**

```
var isSoundOn: String {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSoundOn")
    }

    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.setBool(newValue, forKey: "isSoundOn")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

**CalculatorViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func soundButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard isSoundOn else {
        return
    }

    let filename = "button-16"
    let ext = "mp3"

    [...]
}
```

**SettingsViewController.swift**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let settingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "settingCell", for: indexPath) as! SettingCell
    settingCell.switch.isOn = isSoundOn

    return settingCell
}
```

**SettingCell.swift**

```
class SettingCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var switch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func switchValueChanged() {
        isSoundOn = switch.isOn
    }
}
```